# When does Javascript break the MVC pattern

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I was having an argument with my colleague the other day. It was about building our javascript video player.

I wanted to pass an XML annotations file to the player and then have it parsed the file, then have it displayed the annotations in configurable ways. I thought it'd be easier to embed it everywhere that way.

```
myplayer("divId").setup({
    videoFile: "/video.mp4",
    annotationFile: "/annotations.rdf",
    annotationStyle: "overlay"
});
```

My colleague argued that it would break the pure MVC pattern that we have been following. He would rather parse the annotation file server side and then display it through the View.

What do you all think? Keep in mind we intend to let other projects use this player so we'd like to make it as reusable as possible.

Comment: This is basically a religious debate. The importance of patterns is often overrated and even if it isn't the "best" pattern is subjective. It's a lot like the debate about HTML validation - wether the inconvenience is worth it depends entirely on your personal goals.

Comment: @SpliFF Could you tell me if my idea is sound or not, and why?

Comment: Your idea is sound, so is your friends. Pick the solution you can agree on or toss a coin. It isn't something other people can solve for you. Based on the data provided there is no "correct" answer so i've voted to close.

Comment: I think your colleague is confusing MVC with client server technology in general. There is no reason you cannot do "heavy lifting" in JavaScript and not break MVC. JavaScript isn't just glue for your views.

Comment: @rwilliams his argument is that, suppose he doesnt want to display the annotations using the preconfigured ways, he would have to ask the player for the data and then display it his way.

Comment: @SpliFF this is why I asked SOF to see different opinions on these approaches, because there's no "correct answer". And no, I don't think a coin toss would work in front of my boss.

Comment: SO's terms of service explicitly states there needs to be a correct answer for a question to be valid. This is not a discussion site.

Answer (score 2):

You colleague is confusing MVC with one-M, one-V and one-C. Model, view and controller can be structured in any number of arbitrary layers you want. And being that here another CPU is involved in the browser, you might as well use it (so at least two layers of View). You might decide to parse on the server for many reasons, but "not breaking MVC" wouldn't be one of them.

Comment: Thanks. Would upvote you if I could. Could you tell me the possible reasons to parse on the server?

Comment: @hellocrowley basically the question is whether the browser or the server are in the best position to actually do something with the videoFile, annotationFile and annotationStyle. There might be security concerns (you control the server, not the client) and bandwidth concerns (you want to keep the size small between client and server), but really it comes down to you and your colleague figuring out the advantages/disadvantages to either approach. Both are MVC.